# How to get the array of elements using Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, ormlite, json-deserialization

I need to get a list of orders through Rest API. The JSON from the server looks as follows:

```
{
    "meta":
    {
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "message": "Data was fetched successfully."
    },
    "data":
    {
        "orders":
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "seller": "some value"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "seller": "some value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use `ORMLite`, and the model looks like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Order.TABLE_NAME)
public class Order {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Order";

    @DatabaseField
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String seler;

    public Order() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

`Retrofit 2` is used to perform queries:

```
@GET("/api/orders/get")
Call<RestResponse<List<Order>>> getOrdersList();
```

And, finally, `RestResponse` class is as follows:

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private Meta meta;
    private T data;

    public RestResponse() {
        meta = new Meta();
    }

    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static class Meta {
        private Status status;
        private String message;

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

When performing this query, I get the following error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

The error's reason is clear: callback intends to obtain the object, but gets the array. What can be done in this situation if I want to get an array of elements with `<Order>` type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `data`

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
    private Meta meta;
    private T data;
    ...
}
```

Must be object, not list.

Add `Orders` class:

```
public class Orders {
    List<Order> orders;
    ...
}
```

And modify retrofit call:

```
Call<RestResponse<Orders>> getOrdersList();
```

Comment: However, if the `RestResponse` is used as a generic? The data type depends on what I'm getting from the server. For example, instead of the `orders` can be a single object - `user`.

Comment: Ok, then you must modify your retrofit call: `Call<RestResponse<Data>> getOrdersList();`

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!